# How can I fetch data from my REST API to populate Material Table?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, material-ui, fetch-api, material-table

I am building an application that will request data from an API and display it in an editable table, where the user can edit and update the data base. I am using React with [material-table](https://material-table.com).

I followed this [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/materialtableui-new-array-xng3o) Example and everything work fine with hard coded data. However, I will like to fetch real data from my API end to display in the table. I checked out material table doc but it doesn't resolve my issue.

I initialize the data in the state of the parent component, and pass it as props to the child component that renders the table.

How can I fetch the data real time? Note I am using functional component.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, what is the format of your response or can you paste your API response here as well, or is the hardcoded data is same as your API response?

Comment: {
    "message": "All location records retrieved.",
    "totalRecords": 3,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "f0669917-7159-4e5c-9ac0-d80bb278792f",
            "code": "GEO/234/210",
            "country": "Nigeria",
            "state": "Lagos",
            "lga": 2,
            "landmark": "Urban",
            "communityName": "Oja",
            "locationName": "Hospital",
            "latitude": 66.5678,
            "longitude": -77.76854,
            "updatedAt": "2020-05-11T09:42:45.885Z",
            "deletedAt": null
        },
        { }
    ]
}

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working code [Codesandbok](https://codesandbox.io/s/materialtableui-api-0t7ly) I used fake API to populate the table.

The issue is when the component mounts your props.data is [] and in the Table component you set it as

```
const [gridData, setGridData] = useState({
    data: props.data,
    columns: props.col,
    resolve: () => {},
    updatedAt: new Date()
  });
```

here the data will be assigned as [] & now when the api request happens props.data is populated but your useState is already initialized so the data will still be [].

To fix this you can use props.data as

```
<MaterialTable
    title="Your Title"
    columns={gridData.columns}
    data={props.data} // use props.data to populate the table
    editable={{
      isEditable: rowData => true,
      isDeletable: rowData => true,
      onRowAdd: onRowAdd,
      onRowUpdate: onRowUpdate,
      onRowDelete: onRowDelete
    }}
/>
```

Or you can create an individual state for data & check if its updated or not using useEffect.

Comment: Thanks bro. Let me try it out.

Comment: Do let me know if you face any issues with this.

Comment: Thanks Sahil. I tried it it works although I had to slightly modify my code.